# How can i remove selected attribute from a select2 with Jquery? I want change and not reset it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How can i remove selected attribute from a select2 with Jquery?

I've alredy tried `$("#form_cardtreatment option[value='13']").attr('selected', '');`  - the option with value = 13 is selected. Can anyone help me?

This is the called function:

```
function changetreatmentybycard() {
    alert("{{ treatmentid }}");
    $("#form_cardtreatment option[value='{{ treatmentid }}']").attr('selected', '');
}
```

The "alert" work and print 13, the value off treatment id in twig.

Comment: I didn't get you, but you can try `.prop('selected', false)` instead

Comment: It's work, thank you